# Database field with custom non-editable values

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm pretty new to Entity Framework, so I'm not figuring out how to solve my problem. I have a `User` entity, as follows:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public string Checksum
{
    get
    {
        return Checksum;
    }

    set
    {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(this.Email);
        byte[] encodedBytes = md5.ComputeHash(originalBytes);

        Checksum = BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes);
    }
}
```

The field `Checksum` will not  have user input; I want him to be determined by some logic (the one present at his setter). I'll use it for security checking when I need to update some users sensible data.

I'm on the right path? What's the right way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A setter that does not use `value` anywhere in its body is an indicator of misusing the technology. If a field is read-only, provide only a getter for it. Do not provide a setter if you plan to discard the value being set. Instead, decide on the value(s) upon which the calculated one is dependent, and move the setting logic for your `Checksum` into their setters.

Taking your class is an example, the only dependency here is the `Email` property. You can change your class as follows:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
private string email;
public string Email {
    get { return email; }
    set { email = value; UpdateChecksum(); }
}
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
private string checksum;
public string Checksum {
    get { return checksum; }
}
private void UpdateChecksum() {
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(email);
    byte[] encodedBytes = md5.ComputeHash(originalBytes);
    checksum = BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes);
}
```

Note how `UpdateChecksum` is moved into a separate method. This is useful in situations when you have multiple dependencies: rather than embedding the logic into the individual setters, it is better to move it into a method, and call it as needed.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight, I've understanded the concept. I've passed through some more trouble to be able to map the field for my database since it does not have a setter, but everything is now working as expected :-)